# Trying to parse a specific value in a JS script

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a value that is needed in a POST request. The value can be found multiple times when using Inspect Element on Chrome but since BS4 only looks at the source code I have to scrape the value from a JS script that the site.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">        
    var isSRFlow = true;
    var isPpaOnSignIn =true;
    var simplifyRegFlowSuccess = false;
    var retUrl = "https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.ebay.com&#x2f;";
    var isFB = false;
    var isMobile = false;
    var langCode = "en-US";


    var emailAutoCompleteEnabled = true;

    var dfpContext = '{"enableTMXTagging":"true","slURL":"ebay","flashTagUpgrade":"0","enableFlashTagging":"false","tmxDfpUrl":"https://signin.ebay.com/t_n.html?suppressFlash\u003dtrue\u0026org_id\u003dusllpic0\u0026session_id\u003d57be07a71660ad4e16f42acffffc95e8","swfURL":"ebay","enableSLTagging":"false","swfObjectJSLibURL":"ebay","mid":"AQAAAWZGrHELAAUxNjY1N2JlMDdhNy5hZDRlMTZmLjQyYWNmLmZmZmM5NWU5Jp0dBAKw4k3h8WAm/g97vwVzjcA*","tmxSessionId":"57be07a71660ad4e16f42acffffc95e8","enableHTML5Tagging":"true","flashTagVersion":"1","dfpjsURL":"https://secureir.ebaystatic.com/f/0vk0rkyoky1ltm32dhy0hthnxyx.js"}';
```

I managed to get the entire script by using 
`r = requests.get('https://reg.ebay.com/reg/PartialReg')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
your_script = [script for script in scripts if 'tmxSessionId' in str(script)][0]`

However the only thing that I acutally need is '57be07a71660ad4e16f42acffffc95e8' which are the numbers after "tmxSessionId". How can this be done?

I also tried these:

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
your_script = [script for script in scripts if 'tmxSessionId' in str(script)][0]
new = your_script.find("tmxSessionId")
print(new)
```

as well as using "find_all" instead of just "find". One of my friends also suggested splitting the script but I tried that and found that it didn't work very well. Any thoughts?

P.S: Using broswer based solutions such as selenium and PhantomJS is not something I would like to do as I find it slow and ineffective

Edit:
I used my old code to get the script from the source code and then use what Selçuk suggested

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
your_script = [script for script in scripts if 'tmxSessionId' in str(script)][0]
script_tag = your_script
soup = BeautifulSoup(script_tag, 'lxml')
script = soup.find_all('script')[0]
data = re.findall("{.*?}", script.text)[0]

print(json.loads(data)['tmxSessionId'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know remainder of your script content so i had to close the tag. But it will work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

script_tag = """
<script type ="text/javascript">        
    var isSRFlow = true;
    var isPpaOnSignIn =true;
    var simplifyRegFlowSuccess = false;
    var retUrl = "https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.ebay.com&#x2f;";
    var isFB = false;
    var isMobile = false;
    var langCode = "en-US";


    var emailAutoCompleteEnabled = true;

    var dfpContext = '{"enableTMXTagging":"true","slURL":"ebay","flashTagUpgrade":"0","enableFlashTagging":"false","tmxDfpUrl":"https://signin.ebay.com/t_n.html?suppressFlash\u003dtrue\u0026org_id\u003dusllpic0\u0026session_id\u003d57be07a71660ad4e16f42acffffc95e8","swfURL":"ebay","enableSLTagging":"false","swfObjectJSLibURL":"ebay","mid":"AQAAAWZGrHELAAUxNjY1N2JlMDdhNy5hZDRlMTZmLjQyYWNmLmZmZmM5NWU5Jp0dBAKw4k3h8WAm/g97vwVzjcA*","tmxSessionId":"57be07a71660ad4e16f42acffffc95e8","enableHTML5Tagging":"true","flashTagVersion":"1","dfpjsURL":"https://secureir.ebaystatic.com/f/0vk0rkyoky1ltm32dhy0hthnxyx.js"}';
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(script_tag, 'lxml')
script = soup.find_all('script')[0]
data = re.findall("{.*?}", script.text)[0]

print(json.loads(data)['tmxSessionId'])
```

Output will be

```
57be07a71660ad4e16f42acffffc95e8
```

Comment: So first you got the script (which I can get using the code I posted) and put it all as a variable, then you used BS4 to parse the contents of that variable? And then got the contents as a JSON and printed it?

Comment: Yes. That is all. Maybe you can improve regex and directly get value you want without json parsing

Comment: I just tried it and I got a "NoneType object is not callable" error. I used the original bit of code I that I had to get the script from the site and then used yours to try get the sessionId. I put in "your_script" (from my original code) as "script_tag". The reason I did that is because the SessionID changes everytime